# Activity Diagram Vs Control Flow Graph

Tags: testing

I'm working on Software Test Plan Document and I'm confused about diagram that I should use when making white-box testing. What's the difference between activity diagram and control flow graph? And which one should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An activity diagram represents the behaviour of your system. The actions which the user can make or the system can make are linked with a, control or b, data flow.

The control flow diagram contains the progam logic with weights and guard conditions.

In a software Test Plan I would suggest first to use an activity diagramm to get the general overview. To express explicit logic, you can have an additional control flow diagram.
This depends on you system under test, and you have to chose the right diagram depending what kind of SUT you have. Normally you need several diagrams to give light on different aspects.